# listbox with itemTemplate wp7

Tags: windows-phone-7

How can I show the items in front of image ??

I want the image  images/bl_cell.png repeat with the list items .. this code repeat the photo with items but it doesn't show the items in front of image any one can help by doing this??

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Margin="0,128,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="480">
    <TextBlock x:Name="TextBlock3" Margin="233,440,7,83" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
    <ScrollViewer Margin="-7,0,0,0" x:Name="ss">
        <Grid Height="933" Width="487">
            <ListBox Margin="8,0,0,0" Name="listb" SelectionChanged="listb_SelectionChanged" >
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid Background="{Binding Source=images/bl_cell.png}">
                            <StackPanel>
                                <Image Height="45" Source="images/bl_cell.png" Stretch="Fill" Width="479"  />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't put them in a StackPanel.  Put them all in the same Grid row and column.  When they render, they will render from first to last, back to front, so something like this would show the text over the image:

```
<Grid>
   <Image Source="..." />
   <TextBox Text="This is caption text on the bottom."  VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: still same problem the items doesn't apears in front of image

Comment: <ListBox Margin="8,0,0,0" Name="listb" SelectionChanged="listb_SelectionChanged" >
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
<DataTemplate>
 <Image Height="45" Source="images/bl_cell.png" Stretch="Fill" Width="479"  />
 </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
 </ListBox>

Comment: i fill the list box items from url to xml webservice not by xaml